# what does - do in the sort function? why are we subtracting b from a?

Tags: javascript

```
Array.sort((a,b) => a - b);
```

so i have this typical sort for an Array of numbers. What does the subtract do? why are we subtracting b from a?

Comment: Because this is a simple way of determining which one is higher. When `a` is higher, this will return a positive number. When `b` is higher, it will return a negative number. And when they're equal, it returns `0`. That's what `sort()` needs to know.

Comment: Otherwise you'd have to write something like `a > b ? 1 : (b < a ? -1 : 0)`

Comment: There is a nice description of the `compareFunction` parameter to `Array.sort` here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 1):

If the result is >0 :

`b` goes before `a`

If the result is <0 :

`a` goes before `b`

Answer (score 0):

The sort function returns a number, because values **greater than 0** are sorting **b before a** and values **less than 0** are sorting **a before b**.

So if you are returning `a-b` you are sorting in ascending order (from small to big numbers)

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort